# Uninstall LAMP Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, php, mysql, apache-http-server, lamp

I recently installed a LAMP stack on my Ubuntu 11.10 machine so I can work a little more easily with some of my outside work. However come to find out the lamp stack is conflicting with my core paying job. Now I need to remove apache, mysql, php, and phpmyadmin so I can get back on track with my main paying job.

So question today is how do I uninstall my LAMP packages (cleanly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apt-get remove --auto-remove
```

is your friend. Identify the packages you've installed by hand (by looking at your logs and notes, for example) and remove them, letting auto-remove take care of the rest.